# Is there a __yield() intrinsic on Arm?

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I am trying to compile some code for arm (v7a), that had a

```cpp
#if defined(__arm__)
    __yield();
#endif
```

added in [this pull-request](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp/pull/443)

The other branches have `YieldProcessor()` for MSC and `_mm_pause()` or `__builtin_ia32_pause()` for x86 and x86-64.

The symbol `__yield` is not found by the compiler, a `arm-v7a-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` 7.3.1 with `-mcpu=cortex-a9 -mtune=cortex-a9 -march=armv7-a` options. Is such symbol defined on some other ARM platforms, later Gcc, or Clang?

In the headers that come with the compiler all I could find is `__gnu_parallel::__yield` being an inline wrapper over `sched_yield()`, which I suppose is equivalent to the `std::this_thread::yield()` that the code calls after 100 iterations calling `__yield()`. So I think it's not that. But I didn't see `__yield` in gcc documentation either.

Comment: That's horrifying. If what you write is true, the same code does does *wildly* different things on different platforms, with *very* different performance characteristics. Also, as always, yielding the processor is a sure sign of a hilariously bad program design.

Comment: @EOF It is adding it's own spinlock. I wouldn't do it, but I can't really tell how much it is a useful optimization and how much it is a crawling horror.

Comment: @EOF: AFAICT, `YieldProcessor()`, `_mm_pause()`, and `__builtin_ia32_pause()` all emit the x86 `pause` instruction, so they all seem to be equivalent.  Note this does *not* yield a timeslice to the OS.  Waiting on a spinlock is exactly what it's meant for; it's too short a wait to give up your timeslice, but if you read the lock in a tight loop, the hammering on the cache line degrades performance (and wastes power).  Putting a `pause` instruction in that loop improves things.

Comment: @EOF not horrifying at all. This aligns the CPU to the memory access speed: there is no point in reading faster than the memory can reflect a change. _mm_pause just saves power and frees internal CPU resource instead of needlessly fetching a value at a rate so high that it cannot possibly have changed. This is actually great design and insight from an advanced dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__yield` intrinsic is specified as part of the [ARM C Language Extensions](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0053/latest/) (see 8.4 "Hints").  It emits the [`yield` instruction](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/b/Application-Level-Architecture/Application-Level-Programmers--Model/Exceptions--debug-events-and-checks/The-Yield-instruction?lang=en), which is the rough equivalent of x86 `pause`.  It is intended precisely for situations like waiting on a spinlock; it keeps the CPU from hammering on the cache line excessively (which hurts performance), possibly saves some power, and, in case of a hyperthreading CPU, makes more computational units available to the other logical processor.

(Note that it is purely a CPU function, and not an OS or library call; it doesn't yield a CPU timeslice to the operating system like the similarly named `pause()` or `sched_yield()` or `std::this_thread::yield()` calls would do.)

Although GCC supports some of the ACLE intrinsics, it seems to be missing this one.  You should be able to substitute with `asm volatile("yield");`.  The `yield` instruction has no architectural effect (it executes like `nop`) so no register or memory clobbers are needed.

Comment: In what cases could yield be sensibly used without a memory clobber or acquire barrier?

Comment: @supercat: Well, the `yield` itself does not modify memory, and if using it around something that reads memory that could be modified asynchronously, I'd think it would be the actual memory operation that would have the barriers (e.g. the acquire load or RMW in a spinlock loop).  So I agree there will probably want to be a barrier somewhere in the vicinity, but it needn't go on the `yield` itself, and wherever it goes, it would have to be there anyway whether you had the `yield` or not.

Comment: @supercat: Or are you worried that in a spinlock loop, the machine might reorder the yield with the loads that test the lock, and make the loop spin too fast or too slow?  I think it's a quality-of-implementation issue; the machine just shouldn't do that.  Certainly there is no indication in the architecture reference that you might need barriers for performance.  And it would make no difference to correctness, which should not care whether the yield is there or not.

Answer (score -3):

So in C++ you have std::this_thread::yield()
in C11 you have trd_yield,
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread
both are available in ARM.

Comment: That's a different thing, the question already says they are probably different thing and the accepted answer explains they are indeed different things.

Comment: @midjji: YIELD is an instuction that is just a lager NOP which puts the core into a power mangement state for some cycles. this_thread::yield() just relinquishes the timeslice with the scheduler and puts the current thread at the end of the runnable list. So the one is just a kind of NOP, whereas the other is a expensive kernel call for a differnt purpose.